# Append XML element with Python by xPath and condition

Tags: python, xml, xpath, append, elementtree

I want to append a ET.fromstring element to a XML file, but only if a special condition is fullfilld.

I want to append a new **price** element to the **prices** block, if the .//tariff/name == 'H-AT'.

Here ist my XML exmaple:

```
<tariffimport>
    <tariff>
        <tariffFormula>
            <name>K-Watt</name>
        </tariffFormula>
        <status>1</status>
        <parentTariffId />
        <priority>10</priority>
        <i18n>
            <lang>
                <locale>de_DE</locale>
                <shortDescription />
            </lang>
        </i18n>
        <name>H-AT</name>
        <signatureRequired>false</signatureRequired>
        <termExtension>1</termExtension>
        <termExtensionUnit>5</termExtensionUnit>
        <cancellationPeriod>2</cancellationPeriod>
        <cancellationPeriodUnit>3</cancellationPeriodUnit>
        <contractTerm>2</contractTerm>
        <contractTermUnit>3</contractTermUnit>
        <states />
        <counties />
        <excludeCounties />
        <postalCodes />
        <excludePostalCodes />
        <cities>
            <value>town</value>
        </cities>
        <excludeCities />
        <streets />
        <networkOperatorNos />
        <excludeNetworkOperatorNos />
        <customerGroups>
            <value>PRIVATE</value>
        </customerGroups>
        <media>POWER</media>
        <image>../images/stecker.jpg</image>
        <tariffType>1</tariffType>
        <tariffPart>
            <name>AP_1</name>
            <i18n>
                <lang>
                    <locale>de_DE</locale>
                    <displayName>Arbeitspreis</displayName>
                    <shortName />
                    <description />
                    <attributes>
                        <attribute>
                            <key>minConsumption</key>
                            <value>0</value>
                            <priority>4</priority>
                        </attribute>
                        <attribute>
                            <key>maxConsumption</key>
                            <value>4999</value>
                            <priority>5</priority>
                        </attribute>
                    </attributes>
                </lang>
            </i18n>
            <prices>
                <price>
                    <currency>EUR</currency>
                    <value>0,48018</value>
                    <isPercentage>false</isPercentage>
                    <modifyPart />
                    <validfromdate>01.04.2023</validfromdate>
                </price>
            </prices>
```

I tried checking for within the xpath and with flow controll. But either I append a new **price** element in every **prices** element or nothing happens.

My Problem with the flow controll is, I don't understand how to tell the .append method where the "new" path is. The following expample return a TypeError, becaus of the 'prices_xpath' in the append method. It's just an example to show, where i want to direct and the new block.

```
prices_xpath = './/tariff/tariffPart/prices'
new_price = ET.fromstring("""
                              <price>
                      <currency>EUR</currency>
                                  <value>0,9999</value>
                      <isPercentage>false</isPercentage>
                                  <modifyPart/>
                                  <validfromdate>01.01.2024</validfromdate>
                  </price>
                    """)

for i in root.findall(tariff_token_xpath):
    if i.find('name').text == 'H-AT': 
        i.append(prices_xpath, new_price)
    else:
        pass
```

The other idea was, to check with the xpath, if there is a text = 'H-AT', but **prices** and **price** are no children of **name**. **prices** and **name** are on the same level.

Comment: XML sample is invalid so the question is not a [mcve]. Make it valid and if possible, remove some unnedeed elements to make it more readable.

Comment: Your xml have 3 times a name tags is this right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you will append a second price under prices tag:
(Your xml snippet was not well-formed, I added some tags, please check, if I added it on the right place)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tariffimport>
    <tariff>
        <tariffFormula>
            <name>K-Watt</name>
        </tariffFormula>
        <status>1</status>
        <parentTariffId />
        <priority>10</priority>
        <i18n>
            <lang>
                <locale>de_DE</locale>
                <shortDescription />
            </lang>
        </i18n>
        <name>H-AT</name>
        <signatureRequired>false</signatureRequired>
        <termExtension>1</termExtension>
        <termExtensionUnit>5</termExtensionUnit>
        <cancellationPeriod>2</cancellationPeriod>
        <cancellationPeriodUnit>3</cancellationPeriodUnit>
        <contractTerm>2</contractTerm>
        <contractTermUnit>3</contractTermUnit>
        <states />
        <counties />
        <excludeCounties />
        <postalCodes />
        <excludePostalCodes />
        <cities>
            <value>town</value>
        </cities>
        <excludeCities />
        <streets />
        <networkOperatorNos />
        <excludeNetworkOperatorNos />
        <customerGroups>
            <value>PRIVATE</value>
        </customerGroups>
        <media>POWER</media>
        <image>../images/stecker.jpg</image>
        <tariffType>1</tariffType>
        <tariffPart>
            <name>AP_1</name>
            <i18n>
                <lang>
                    <locale>de_DE</locale>
                    <displayName>Arbeitspreis</displayName>
                    <shortName />
                    <description />
                    <attributes>
                        <attribute>
                            <key>minConsumption</key>
                            <value>0</value>
                            <priority>4</priority>
                        </attribute>
                        <attribute>
                            <key>maxConsumption</key>
                            <value>4999</value>
                            <priority>5</priority>
                        </attribute>
                    </attributes>
                </lang>
            </i18n>
            <prices>
                <price>
                    <currency>EUR</currency>
                    <value>0,48018</value>
                    <isPercentage>false</isPercentage>
                    <modifyPart />
                    <validfromdate>01.04.2023</validfromdate>
                </price>
            </prices>
        </tariffPart>
    </tariff>
</tariffimport>"""

new_price = ET.fromstring("""<price>
  <currency>EUR</currency>
  <value>0,9999</value>
  <isPercentage>false</isPercentage>
  <modifyPart />
  <validfromdate>01.01.2024</validfromdate>
</price>""")

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

t = [tex.text for tex in root.findall('.//name')]
if 'H-AT' in t:
    price = root.find('.//prices')
    price.append(new_price)

ET.indent(root, space="  ")
ET.dump(root)
#root.write("new.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output (shorted):

```
…
<prices>
        <price>
          <currency>EUR</currency>
          <value>0,48018</value>
          <isPercentage>false</isPercentage>
          <modifyPart />
          <validfromdate>01.04.2023</validfromdate>
        </price>
        <price>
          <currency>EUR</currency>
          <value>0,9999</value>
          <isPercentage>false</isPercentage>
          <modifyPart />
          <validfromdate>01.01.2024</validfromdate>
        </price>
      </prices>
    </tariffPart>
  </tariff>
</tariffimport>
```